# Bash - List PID's of processses which have more than six descendant processes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, process

Suppose there is a process `dummy.sh` whose pid is 101 & has seven descendants:

```
pstree -pc 101
dummy(101)──dummy(102)──dummy(103)──dummy(104)──dummy(105)──dummy(106)──sleep(107)
```

But how to fetch PID's of all the process in Bash script which has more than six(in our example dummy.sh 101) descendants. I do not want PID's of process whose descendants are less than six.

I tried `PS -u myuser` but it only displays all user process. But how to get PID's of user processes which have descendants greater than six ?

**Update:**

For example purpose I use below recursive script to trigger seven straight chain of descendants. I want to get PID 101 as it has more than six descendants.

Similarly as this dummy process is triggered by bash(100) terminal which will be parent to dummy(101) then I want Pid 100 as well (as it also meets the condition of having more than six descendants).
`bash(100)──dummy(101)──dummy(102).....dummy(107)`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]]; then
    set -- 7
fi

if [[ "$1" -gt 2 ]]; then
    echo 'descendant process' "$1"
    "$0" "$(($1 - 1))"
else
    sleep 500
fi
```

**Criteria:**
I will consider only the PID's returned by `ps -u $USER -o pid` command. As my requirement is only to consider user preprocess. I will loop them to find if a user process has more than six descendants, but my question is how do i find descendants count for a particular PID ?

Comment: I've got an `smbd` process with three immediate descendants, i.e. not in a chain. Run this code to output the example as if from `pstree` - `echo 'smbd(1076)─┬─cleanupd(1130)'; echo '           ├─lpqd(1147)'; echo '           └─smbd-notifyd(1126)'`. In the context of your question does that count as three descendants, or one descendant three times?

Comment: My example includes descendants of descendants like a chain. In my example dummy(101) has one child i,e dummy(102).

But also dummy(101) has six descendants.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. I'm asking about my example. Or perhaps your question relates to a _chain_ of six descendants, rather than just six descendants?

Comment: Yes chain of six descendants, not just six descendants. Sorry I was unable to understand your given example chain in the comment. It didn't format well.

Comment: @MudassirHussain  Two issues there. (a) If you were looking for more than four descendants, then 101, 102 and 103 each has four or more -- they overlap. (b) Descendants form a tree, not necessarily balanced. Possibly you want to identify the single root process of any process tree that contains at least seven processes (including itself), but your aim is not clear.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I'm very new to bash. I apologize. For now I want to get PID of a process which has more than six chain of Descendants. If any descendant has more than six chain of descendants. Is there any way to do this with PS or awk ? Or i need to loop all PID's of a user? which seems redundant ?

Comment: In your example, 101 might have a parent of 80, and in turn that process will have a parent of PID 1. Ultimately, all processes belong to a chain from 1, so the answer to your question is potentially just to list PID 1. This is a user process (as in, it's not a kernel process). Or did you mean we should only consider processes owned by the current user?

Comment: @MudassirHussain  A chain is just a special case of a tree: you could have a direct chain that also has a bunch of side branches -- is that included? `ps` will tell you all the pids for the current user, or process group, or whatever you pick. `awk` will (with some effort) do a recursive trace on any or all of your processes to reconstruct a tree (and measure its depth). But the connections are all parent<-child only, so any linkage has to backtrack from all possible child processes. A parent can know its multiple children, but there is no direct way to make it tell you.

Comment: @roaima I have updated the question for better understanding.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear. Looking on a system here, I've got processes owned by my `bash` login shell. No problem. But that shell is owned by `sshd`, which in turn is owned by another instance of `sshd`, and that is owned by the master `sshd` running as `root`. Yet that itself has a parent of `1`. At what point do we stop considering parents?

Comment: @roaima We will consider only the PID's returned by `ps -u $USER -o pid` command, assuming all PID's returned by that command belongs to user process.

Comment: I don't see that in your question. Please add it, as it's a really important clarification

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a much more efficient way of doing this, but this works:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A procs
ps -u $USER --no-headers -o pid,ppid | (

    # build an associate array that maps pids to parent pids
    while read pid ppid ; do
        procs[$pid]=$ppid
    done

    # for each process, walk up the tree, counting processes
    for pid in "${!procs[@]}"; do
        save_pid=$pid
        depth=0
        while :; do
            ppid=${procs[$pid]}
            [[ $ppid ]] || break

            let depth++
            pid=$ppid
        done
        if (( depth > 6 )); then
            echo $save_pid
        fi
    done
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also browse the /proc filesystem. For every process running there is a file called "children" where all direct descendants are listed space-separated.

For process 12345 for instance you will find the information about its child processes in:

/proc/12345/task/12345/children